# RxJS assign observable and get data in one stream

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, pipeline

I am trying to assign Observable at first and then subscribe to its values. This code:

```
//assign observable
    this.messagesDataSource$ = this.messageService.getMessagesDataSource(this.messagesContainerTitle);

//subscribe to its values     
    this.messagesDataSource$.subscribe((messages: Message[]) => {
                            this.messagesArray = messages;
                        });
```

works fine but I don;t think if this is good approach.. I've tried to make this run with pipe() but still if there is no  subscription data array will not be assigned. My third idea was to use map

```
this.messagesDataSource$ =
        this.messageService.getMessagesDataSource(this.messagesContainerTitle)
            .map(messages => this.messagesArray = messages)
```

but still no result. Can you give me any hint how to assign observable and then get its data in one stream?

**EDIT**

map() in a pipe is also not fired there:

```
this.messagesDataSource$ =
this.messageService.getMessagesDataSource(this.messagesContainerTitle)
            .pipe(
                map((messages) => {
                console.log('in pipe');
                return messages
            }))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "If there is no subscription data array will not be assigned." Are you trying to subscribe and get the last values that were emitted?

Comment: Exactly, at first I have to assign an observable because messageService.getMessagesDataSource() depends on some condition and it can return different data. When observable will be assigned i have to subscribe to it to get its data.

Comment: Do you want to iterate the loop by using this variable `messagesDataSource`? if yes then you can use `async` pipe. so no need to subscribe that observable.

Comment: Hi Yash Rami. But map is not firing there. Look at my edit.

Comment: @MateuszGebroski Okay but why don't you map the response inside the `getMessagesDataSource` function from messageService?

Comment: because I have to use both async and its data.

Answer (score 3):

Observables are **lazy** in the sense that they only execute values when something subscribes to it

In your second approach you are not subscribing to Observable that's why you are not getting any data. You will get data when you subscribe to it.

For the same reason, your `map` operator is also not working. the `map` operator will trigger when you subscribes to the Observable.

If you are not using `messagesDataSource$` anywhere else in your code than you can omit the extra assignment and directly subscribe to the `Observable` returned.

```
this.messageService.getMessagesDataSource(this.messagesContainerTitle)
  .subscribe(messages => this.messagesArray = messages)
```

Or if you want to do this in view you can use `async` pipe which automatically subscribes to your Observable under the hood